# python access array from another class

Tags: python-2.7

good day guys. i have a problem calling the *filespath* array from VideoForm class. comments and suggestions would be highly appreciated. thanks.

sample code:

```
import os
from ffvideo import VideoStream
filespath = []
vidDuration = []
vidCode = [] 
class getVidInfo(QtCore.QThread):
      def __init__(self):
          AtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
      def run(self):
          for x in xrange(14)
             filename = filespath[x]
             filename = os.path.basename(filename)
             vs = VideoStream(filename)
             vidDuration.append(vs.duration)
             vidCodec.append(vs.codec_name)
class VideoForm(AtGui.MainWindow)
      def getVideoFile(self):
          for dirName, subDirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir)
              for fname in fileList:
                  ext = fname[-3:]
                  if ext in ['flv','mp4','avi','mkv']
                     filespath.append(os.path.join(dirName, fname))
```

Comment: problem here sir "filename = filespath[x]"

Answer (score 0):

filespath is a "global" variable, outside the class method scope in this case. If you want to modify this from within the class method, you need to declare the variable as global in the method explicitly:

```
class VideoForm(AtGui.MainWindow)
    def getVideoFile(self):
        global filespath # declare explicitly the intention of using the global one.
        for dirName, subDirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir)
            for fname in fileList:
            ext = fname[-3:]
            if ext in ['flv','mp4','avi','mkv']
                filespath.append(os.path.join(dirName, fname))
```

Though this is not recommended, unless you know what you are doing. It is preferable to pass in the list as a parameter, say, to the class constructor perhaps.